# How can I improve aiming in Resident Evil 6?

Tags: resident-evil-6

Is there a way to make the reticle smaller for firearms? Or, the laser less jittery?

Skills, cheats, modding - anything goes.

I would like the most immediate solution possible - I'm not sure I'll be able to stomach playing anymore until some "suck less at aiming" unlock becomes available.

Comment: Use quickshots and you dont`t have to aim :)

Comment: @IvanSolntsev and how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

There IS no "suck less at aiming" unlock, or anything of the sort. Sadly, you're stuck to what you have right now.

There are some people who prefer using Mouse+Keyboard, due to the aiming reticle being slightly more precise than the aiming laser sight, but either way, skill and getting used to the controls is all you have for this game. If anything, I suggest you try your hand at playing on Amateur difficulty until you feel comfortable with the controls, and then, as you go up through higher difficulties, try switching to spread-fire weapons like machine guns and shotguns.

Comment: Pretty sure laser sight/reticle doesn't depend on your input mode. naturally, I'm playing with a mouse.

Comment: Well, from what I've seen myself (considering I play with a controller), the laser sight used with a gamepad IS considerably more unstable and less precise than the mouse-based reticle. Or at least  that's what I myself have noticed.

Comment: You can choose to use either a laser sight or a reticle with a mouse, I assume it is the same for gamepads.

Comment: Well, blame it on the fact that I've never used anything but a laser sight on a mouse. Plus I'm so used to it, it'd probably feel awkward to use a reticle now. =p

Comment: There *are* skills to make aiming less difficult: "lock on" and "recoil".

Answer (score 1):

change speed under camera settings.. took me forever to find; but after trying a whole bunch to "aim for the dynamite" with the impossibly slow aiming, I started to look for options.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Quick Shot](http://residentevil.wikia.com/Quick_Shot), you will attack nearest enemy. No need to aim :)

http://game.capcom.com/manual/bio6/nl/page-122.html

> *Quick Shot*
>
> Simultaneous left & right click

Comment: Are quickshots automatic headshots? Because I can already shoot the center of mass.

Comment: No, they are not headshots, but they stagger enemies, leaving them open to meele finishing moves.